# Does Visual Studio 2013 provide an improvement on c++11's high_performance_clock?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I've read that in Visual Studio 2012, the `high_performance_clock` defined in c++11 is actually implemented as a synonym for `system_clock` instead of what it should be i.e. 
a clock that has the maximum resolution that can be provided by the system.

Has this been fixed in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: What is more scary is that the `steady_clock` of VS is awfully unsteady.

Comment: That's true unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. However:

> I didn't have time to fix this in 2013 RTM (we had barely enough time to overhaul the STL for variadic templates), but I hope to be able to fix this for the next major version. Note that all of the clocks need to be reimplemented, as tracked by several active bugs. -- Steven T. Lavavej ([from here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/))

So hopefully in VS 2014 :/

Comment: Great, I'll look forward to VS 2014 then

Comment: @RKG The VS 14 preview release notes say that all the clocks have been rewritten. Unfortunately you can't install it side-by-side with 2013

Answer (score 1):

No. However, if you are interested, boost::chrono has high_resolution_clock and is almost a drop in replacement for the c++11 high_performance_clock that does work properly on windows.

[boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.high_resolution_clock)